# Figure positioning correction

Tags: floats, positioning

I am finding incredibly tough to align a one particular figure in my report. Somehow this figure gets automatically positioned in the extreme right position.Here is my code for the same. Could anyone help me with the error/ positioning ?

```
     \begin{figure}[ht]
     \begin{picture}(1,6.85)
        \put(1.3,2.0){\includegraphics[width=12.0cm,scale=15.20]                     {figures/orthography_specimen_final.eps}}
        \end{picture}
        \caption{deep drawn component}           
     \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where do you want the graph to be positioned? Centered on the text block?

Answer (score 1):

Not having access to the file `orthography_specimen_final.eps` makes it admittedly tough to provide a definitive diagnosis of what may be going on.

Unless there's a specific and compelling reason for *not* placing an image centered on the text block, it's almost always best to simply center the image. If that's acceptable for the case of your figure, you could simplify the code in the `figure` float by omitting the `picture` environment and related commands and using a simple `\centering` instruction instead.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12.0cm,scale=15.20]{figures/orthography_specimen_final.eps}
\caption{deep drawn component}           
\end{figure}
```